# Getting start and end values from a text file in c# using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to write a c# program which reads text from a .txt file. As well as reading from a file, I want it to read from a specific area in the text file so declaring start and end position using regex. 
For instance, my text file may contain the following phrase:

"seconds and server timestamp is '1468315683' seconds Finished preHandle "

and I may want to read values  in between **server** and **Finished**

I am trying to achieve this using the code below, the program runs successfully but does not log the values.

```
        string text;
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\FOLDER\FILE.txt");
        while((text = file.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            if(text.Contains("server") )
            {

                var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\server ).*?(?=\Finished)");
                foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))

                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
       }
```

Comment: `(?<=server).*?(?=Finished)`; *do not escape* 's' and 'F': `\s` means *whitespace*

Comment: I have tried that aswell but still no luck, its not reading the values

Comment: `new Regex(@"(?s)server (.*?)Finished")` and then `Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);`. And why `while((text = file.ReadToEnd()) != null)`? Just `var text = file.ReadToEnd();` is enough. Use `using` when reading a file with `StreamReader`.

Comment: @r1993: any feedback? Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38372155/3832970).

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, this has worked. however is there a way to include special characters in the regular expression such as [ ]{ } ?

Comment: the text file may have special characters such as [ ] which do not get read

Comment: If you want a user to be notified via a comment, use `@`+`username`. I read your comment because someone upvoted my answer. To match a `[`, you need to escape it: `@"\["`, or use inside a character class like `[[]`. The `]` can be used as is outside character classes, but requires escaping inside if it is not the first char in the char class - `[]]` / or `[{}\]]`. The `{` and `}` do not require escaping at all unless they denote a limiting quantifier (i.e. in `{1,5}` they are special, it means *repeat the quantified subpattern on the left 1 to 5 times*)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fix your code as follows:

```
string text;
using (var file = new StreamReader(@"C:\FOLDER\FILE.txt")) 
{
    text = file.ReadToEnd();
    if (text.Contains("server") )
    {
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)server(.*?)Finished"))
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

POIs:

- Use `using` when reading/writing files in order to release the objects automatically once finished
- The regex should know that `.` matches any symbol by adding the DOTALL modifier `(?s)`
- A capturing group approach is much more efficient than lookaround-based one, use `server(.*?)Finished` to capture the text between `server` and `Finished` into `Groups[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not *escape* `s` and `F`; another suggestion is using *Linq* instead of readers:

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\FOLDER\FILE.txt")
  .SelectMany(line => Regex
     .Matches(line, @"(?<=server\s+).*?(?=\s+Finished)")
     .OfType<Match>())
  .Select(match => match.Value);

// "timestamp is '1468315683' seconds" 
// for the one line file (the line has been taken from the question) 
foreach (string found in lines)
  Console.WriteLine(found);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I have tried this before aswell and still does not get the values

Comment: @r1993: Could you, please, provide the test phrase (extracted from the file) since I've run my routine (on the file with one line) and it has returned the expected value.